# how can drag and drop button app?xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a button that can drag and drop in app.  how can drag and drop button in app?

```
var layout = new LinearLayout (this);
layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
var aButton = new Button (this);
aButton.Text = "Say Hello!";
layout.AddView (aButton);
SetContentView (layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a button that can drag and drop in app. how can drag and drop button in app?

You can implement Drag and Drop by following steps:

1. Create your xaml file with `AbsoluteLayout`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDrapDrop"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Button To Drag"/>
   </AbsoluteLayout>
   ```
2. Register the Long Click event of the button as the Drag and Drop event and call `View.StartDrag` in the event:

   ```
   Button btnDrapDrop;
   ...
   btnDrapDrop.LongClick += BtnDrapDrop_LongClick;
   ...
   private void BtnDrapDrop_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
   {
       ClipData dragData = ClipData.NewPlainText("", "");
       View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(btnDrapDrop);
       btnDrapDrop.StartDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
   }
   ```
3. Register the `Drag` event of the `AbsoluteLayout` to receive the drop and translate the button when user drops:

   ```
   AbsoluteLayout layout;
   ...
   layout.Drag += BtnDrapDrop_Drag;
   ...
   private void BtnDrapDrop_Drag(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
   {
       AbsoluteLayout layout = (AbsoluteLayout)sender;

       switch (e.Event.Action)
       {
           case DragAction.Drop:
               float x=e.Event.GetX();
               float y = e.Event.GetY();
               btnDrapDrop.TranslationX = x;
               btnDrapDrop.TranslationY = y;
               layout.Invalidate();
               return;
       }
   }
   ```

Here is the complete Activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnDrapDrop;
    AbsoluteLayout layout;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Second);
        btnDrapDrop=FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDrapDrop);
        layout = FindViewById<AbsoluteLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);

        //register the  long click event of drap button
        btnDrapDrop.LongClick += BtnDrapDrop_LongClick;
        //register the drag event of the layout
        layout.Drag += BtnDrapDrop_Drag;
    }

    private void BtnDrapDrop_Drag(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        AbsoluteLayout layout = (AbsoluteLayout)sender;

        switch (e.Event.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Drop:
                float x=e.Event.GetX();
                float y = e.Event.GetY();
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationX = x;
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationY = y;
                layout.Invalidate();
                return;
        }
    }

    private void BtnDrapDrop_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipData dragData = ClipData.NewPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(btnDrapDrop);
        btnDrapDrop.StartDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
    }
}
```

For Details of Drap and Drop in Android, please refer to [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).